# webserver: php.ini changes not taking effect

Tags: php, apache

According to `phpinfo()` the following `php.ini` files are loaded:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/cgi
Loaded Configuration File   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d
```

I've made changes to `php.ini` found in `/etc/php5/cgi` - restarted server - NO Effect.

This file: `/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/etc/php.ini` has the note:

> DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY, SO ALL
>   YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

The server has these `php.ini` files

> ```
> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
> /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
> /opt/psa/admin/conf/php.ini
> /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/etc/php.ini
> ```

Could you please tell me which php.ini file should I look for?

Comment: If you are using WAMP or something similar, you need to make changes via the system tray icon. It automatically generates the .ini files from some magical happy place - it doesn't use the actual files stored in the places you would expect them to be read from.

Comment: It is linux web virtual server with ubuntu OS.

Comment: check whether you are really permitted to do so with the hosting company

Comment: I will double check with them. But it let's me make changes it does save those changes... I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add something to php.ini (as xdebug properties, for example), then you should use /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d folder (create or edit one of that files).

As for php.ini located in cgi - seems right that you've done. However, there still exists a possibility, that you can edit these files, but they are overwritten by general configuration by your provider. I would advice to check it locally, if the same configuration would work.
EDIT: /opt/psa/admin/conf/php.ini looks like a possibility of this variant.

Also I would advice to edit apache's php.ini, but it looks more like a magic path.

Comment: Wonderful. It worked. Thank you. Your first suggestion `/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d` worked fine. I just added `.ini` file with variable I want to change.

Comment: Solved my bug finally, I love you, Russian guy.

Answer (score 1):

I had a syntax error at 1. line!

It was :[php] instead of [php].
PHP ignored my config file because it couldn't see a php section

For me that fixed everything; Run `php -c 'path-to-php.ini'`. It will show you more information.